# There is no SafeArea option for xib files

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, iphone-x

I'm trying to update my apps for the iPhoneX and there is no 'SafeArea' guides. Are they only in Storyboards, not individual nibs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Safe Area Layout Guides are also available in nibs. When you create a new nib file in Xcode 9 they will be automatically activated. If you your nibs were created with Xcode 8 (or older) you have to activate them:

1. Select your nib file in the **Project Navigator**:

[image]

2. Activate Safe Area Layout Guides in the **File Inspector**:

[image]

To activate the Safe Area Layout Guides for a **Storyboard** you have to also select the **Scene** in the editor to get the checkbox in the File Inspector.